# Nuget pack does not include external package source

Tags: nuget, nuget-spec

I have written a little library for Sitecore(a CMS product) which means my library depends on Sitecore. Sitecore, the company, have recently made their product available as nuget packages. However they have chosen to host their own nuget package source. 
When I use `nuget spec/pack myLibrary.csproj` to generate a nuget package, only the nuget packages from the official package source are included as dependencies.
Is it possible to include dependencies from another package source in nuget packages?
Or maybe I should ask, how do you go about creating packages from alternative package sources ?